# Can which-key help with extended keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: key-bindings, help

I have two shortcuts defined like this

```el
;; eval in shell
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c x s") 'eir-eval-in-shell)

;; eval in ruby
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c x r") 'eir-eval-in-ruby)
```

`which-key` helps me when I forgot my keyboard shortcuts.

The problem is, When I press C-c and wait 1 second I don't
get any useful info about the above 2 combos.

What I get is

```
& → +prefix     e → er/expand-region h → experiment-001 m → experiment-002 → +projectile-command-map
b → bury-buffer f → ffap             i → experiment-003    o → experiment-005 x → +prefix
C-c-  [C-h paging/help]
```

But

```
x → +prefix
```

doesn't help. Any ideas what to do here?

Answer (score 2):

- Use `define-prefix-command` to define a *named* prefix
- Bind `C-c x` to that prefix command
- Bind `s` and `r` in the prefix command keymap

When you type `C-c`, `which-key` will then show you your chosen prefix name instead of just "prefix", which gives you better context for which commands you can expect to be bound underneath it.

Obviously you can type `x` (with or without doing the above) to see the bindings themselves.