# How can I add a name to prefixes?

Tags: key-bindings

My current config looks like this:

```
(use-package general
    :ensure t
    :config (general-define-key
    :states '(normal visual insert emacs)
    :prefix "SPC"
    :non-normal-prefix "C-SPC"

    ;; Buffer.
    "b k" '(kill-this-buffer :which-key "Kill Buffer")
))
```

But when I press `SPC` it shows `+prefix` next to `b` instead of an actual name. How can I set a name there with :which-key?

Comment: See also https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/53170/can-which-key-help-with-extended-keyboard-shortcuts

Answer (score 3):

You can give SPC and SPC-b a description for which-key by using the `:ignore` keyword:

```lisp
(general-define-key
 :states '(normal visual insert emacs)
 :keymaps 'override
 :prefix "SPC"
 :non-normal-prefix "C-SPC"
 "" '(:ignore t :which-key "description for SPC") ; <<< added
 ;; Buffer.
 "b" '(:ignore t :which-key "description for b") ; <<< added
 "b k" '(kill-this-buffer :which-key "Kill Buffer"))
```

[image]

This is shown in the example in the [Which Key Integration](https://github.com/noctuid/general.el#which-key-integration) section on the github page.